# MySQL remove special characters using Regex

Tags: mysql, regex

I want to remove special characters from a MySQL table but LEAVE UTF8 characters such as arabic.

This is to remove common special characters such as " ' @ ! * $ etc.

I have used the following in PHP which works great.

```
preg_replace('/(?=\P{Nd})\P{L}/u', '', $name);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can UPDATE your rows using the very same regular expression for comparison.

The string regular expression operators in MySQL are REGEXP or RLIKE.
I hope, this should solve your problem. :)

Comment: Something like this? (although this doesn't work)

`UPDATE `accounts`.`accounts` SET `name` = REPLACE(`name`,'/(?=\P{Nd})\P{L}/u', '')
WHERE `name` REGEXP `/(?=\P{Nd})\P{L}/u`;
`

Comment: And, you may also use LIKE. It is said to make the query faster than when compared using REGEXP.

Comment: The query does not work and returns Unknown column '/(?=\P{Nd})\P{L}/u' in 'where clause'

Comment: I did some research, and as it seems to me, MYSQL doesn't support regex replace yet. If you are using MariaDB you can perform something like this...
REGEXP_REPLACE(col, regexp, replace)
else you can create a stored procedure like the one shown [here](https://techras.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/regex-replace-for-mysql/)